# Flutter How to cause a new gesture

Tags: flutter, gesture

I have a listview which has Slideable
I want a longPress gesture to activate a Slideable Action.
I can get a longpress message, but I do not know what to do to cause the sliding action to work.
This is a custom Tile Widget I need to edit.

This is what it looks like when I swipe.
I want the same thing to happen when I release the longpress

[image]

Code is below:

```
class BookmarkListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  // final BookmarkPageViewModel bookmarkViewmodel;
  // final int index;

  const BookmarkListTile(
      {Key? key, required this.bookmark, this.onTap, this.onDelete})
      : super(key: key);
  final Bookmark bookmark;
  final Function(Bookmark bookmark)? onDelete;
  final Function(Bookmark bookmark)? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onLongPressUp: () {
          print("longpress");
          // add code here to cause the Slidable Action to happen

        },
        child: Slidable(
          actionPane: const SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
          secondaryActions: [
            IconSlideAction(
              icon: Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.red,
              onTap: () {
                if (onDelete != null) onDelete!(bookmark);
              },
            )
          ],
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              if (onTap != null) onTap!(bookmark);
            },
            title: Text(bookmark.note),
            subtitle: Text(PaliScript.getScriptOf(
                language:
                    context.read<ScriptLanguageProvider>().currentLanguage,
                romanText: bookmark.bookName!)),
            trailing: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text('${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.page} -'),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    '${bookmark.pageNumber}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by **" what to do to cause the sliding action to work"** this is unclear or  is it like you want to do something when you swipe left/right if thats the case then you should use  Dismissible widget for more info check this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible

Comment: I want the long press (release) to do the swipe action.  There is a nice UI to delete the object.  I want that action to happen (it displays a red trashcan)  clicking the trash can does the work.  Otherwise, I need to manage a lot of things.  added picture of what happens with swipe.  I want the longPressUp to cause that same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maybe this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
          actionPane: const SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
          secondaryActions: [
            IconSlideAction(
              icon: Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.red,
              onTap: () {
                if (onDelete != null) onDelete!(bookmark);
              },
            )
          ],
          child: Builder(builder: (context) =>
             GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onLongPress: () {
         openSlidable(context);
        },
       child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              if (onTap != null) onTap!(bookmark);
            },
            title: Text(bookmark.note),
            subtitle: Text(PaliScript.getScriptOf(
                language:
                    context.read<ScriptLanguageProvider>().currentLanguage,
                romanText: bookmark.bookName!)),
            trailing: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text('${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.page} -'),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    '${bookmark.pageNumber}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  )),
                ],
              ),
          ),
        ))));
  }


 void openSlidable(BuildContext context) {
    final slidable = Slidable.of(context);
    final isClosed = slidable.renderingMode == SlidableRenderingMode.none;
    if (isClosed) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        if (slidable.mounted) {
                    slidable.open(actionType: SlideActionType.secondary);

        }
      });
    }
  }
```

This will automatically open your slidable if it was closed. Child of `Slidable` should be wrapped in `Builder` in order to work.

Comment: I got the code to work with adding an actiontype.  This was very useful and helpful for me.  I think there is a bug in the Slideable code because if you close the tile that is open, its state is still "open" and can only called once.  However, I'll place an issue with that pkg unless you think there is something i can do manually..